# How can I set the Undertow MAX_ENTITY_SIZE in WildFly

Tags: file-upload, jax-rs, wildfly, undertow

I want to upload files directly as an `InputStream` body to a JAX-RS `POST` request. But the body is limited to 10MB by default, which is too small for some of my files. I found a configuration option [MAX_ENTITY_SIZE](https://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-2.0.0/#common-listener-options), but how can I set those in WildFly? I didn't find anything in the jboss-cli.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the jboss-cli.sh, you would do something like:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https/:write-attribute(name=max-post-size,value=104857600)
```

(assuming HTTPS) where 104857600 is now 100MB or so.

This modifies the appropriate `standalone.xml` to have:

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" max-post-size="104857600" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I didn't find anything in the docs, because I searched for `MAX_ENTITY_SIZE`... if it applies to all http methods (e.g. also PUT) I think it's not a good idea to name it `max-post-size`. BTW: I had to use the `http` listener (withou `s`), e.g.: `/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:write-attribute(name=max-post-size,value=104857600L)`